# How to upload and read an excel file (.xlsx) in a blazor server project

Tags: asp.net-core, blazor, blazor-server-side, asp.net-blazor

I have a blazor server project and I need to send an excel file with data to create objects of an entity. I have searched a lot and have not found anything that has worked for me. I believe my problem is accessing the file to then be able to do what I want.

In my blazor component i have:

```cs
<InputFile OnChange="@ImportExcelFile" accept=".xlsx" multiple="false"></InputFile>
@code {
    async Task ImportExcelFile(InputFileChangeEventArgs e)
    {
        await EnrollmentService.CreateEnrollmentByExcel(e);
    }
}
```

In my `EnrollmentService.cs` i need to read file.

If anyone can help me I would be very grateful.

Comment: You tagged your question with EPPlus - how does that relate to your question? What's the connection?

Comment: @mason Because one of the ways to read excel files is with epplus, maybe I shouldn't have put that tag, but people with experience with that library could help me

Comment: Yes, it's a relevant library. However, just tagging your question with libraries that could possibly be used to solve the problem isn't good for organization purposes. If you know about EPPlus, then surely you can visit the documentation and see what sort of input it takes to read Excel data, then see if in Blazor you can get an uploaded file in the same format, or at least convert it over. What's stopping you from doing that?

Comment: @mason Okey, sorry, I don't often ask many questions here, I can't access my file before I get to a reading library for example.

Comment: [The documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/blazor/file-uploads?view=aspnetcore-7.0&pivots=server) describes how to read a user provided file. I've never done this using Blazor, but Googling "blazor access file on client side" had it as the 2nd result. When you want to do something that's clearly been done before, such as read a file, keep in mind that the answer is usually just a search away. If you try out the documentation and get stuck, then a question might be more appropriate at that point.

Comment: I already read this and tried to do it, I also searched here and found someone complaining that it didn't work, I'll continue to search and try to find a solution to the problem, as soon as I find it I'll share it here

Comment: I linked you to the documentation that shows you how to do it. The code in your question doesn't show you following that documentation. Please follow it. If you get stuck, create a [mcve] so that we can clearly see what you're trying. The documentation shows how to access a stream containing the file, and EPPlus takes a stream. Should be doable - you just need to try.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I can already access my entered file, I was researching and found several ways but it didn't satisfy my requirements because they were trying to store the file in a folder, I just wanted to read the data and store it in memory, and I got this that helped me. Thanks.

```cs
async Task ImportExcelFile(InputFileChangeEventArgs e)
{
    foreach (var file in e.GetMultipleFiles(1))
    {
        try
        {
            using (MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream())
            {
                // copy data from file to memory stream
                await file.OpenReadStream().CopyToAsync(ms);
                // positions the cursor at the beginning of the memory stream
                ms.Position = 0;

                // create ExcelPackage from memory stream
                ExcelPackage.LicenseContext = LicenseContext.NonCommercial;
                using (ExcelPackage package = new ExcelPackage(ms))
                {
                    ExcelWorksheet ws = package.Workbook.Worksheets.FirstOrDefault();
                    int colCount = ws.Dimension.End.Column;
                    int rowCount = ws.Dimension.End.Row;
                    var s = ws.Cells[2, 2].Value;
                    // rest of the code here...
                }
            }
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            throw;
        }
    }
}
```